# Associating the correct teams with the correct score values

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have some code which outputs the teams and all their score values (without spaces) from the page http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01")

content = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

listnames = ''
listscores = ''

for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='scores'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
            if cell.text.isdigit():
                listscores += cell.text
        for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores team'):
            listnames += cell.text

print (listnames)
print (listscores)
```

The problem that I can't solve is that I don't quite understand how Python can use any extracted information and give the correct teams their correct integer values in a format like this:

```
Team X: 1, 5, 11.
```

The issue with the website is that all scores are under the same class; all tables are under the same class. The only thing different is the href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to associate values with names, a `dict` is usually the way to go. Here's a modification of your code to demonstrate the principle:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen('http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01')

content = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

results = {}

for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='scores'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        scores = []
        name = None
        for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
            link = cell.find('a')
            if link:
                name = link.text
            elif cell.text.isdigit():
                scores.append(cell.text)
        if name is not None:
            results[name] = scores

for name, scores in results.items():
    print('%s: %s' % (name, ', '.join(scores)))
```

... which gives this output when run:

```
$ python3 get_scores.py
St. Louis: 1, 2, 1
San Jose: 0, 3, 0
Colorado: 0, 0, 2
Dallas: 0, 0, 0
New Jersey: 0, 1, 0
NY Islanders: 2, 0, 1
Nashville: 0, 0, 2, 0
Minnesota: 0, 1, 0
Detroit: 1, 2, 0
NY Rangers: 1, 1, 2
Anaheim: 0, 3, 1
Winnipeg: 2, 0, 0
Chicago: 1, 1, 0, 0
Calgary: 0, 0, 1
Vancouver: 0, 1, 1
Edmonton: 3, 0, 1
Montreal: 1, 1, 2
Carolina: 1, 0, 0
```

Apart from the use of a dictionary, the other significant change is that we're now checking for the existence of an `a` element to get the team's name, rather than an additional `team` class. That's really a stylistic choice, but to me the code seems more expressive this way.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, assuming that (it works, though), if I had multiple links with different names (let's keep it simple) such as W and L (Win and Loss) and I wanted it to show like this: TEAM X: W: 25. L: 16, how would I go about approaching that? @ZeroPiraeus

Comment: @NathanielElder I'm not completely clear what you're asking, to be honest; in any event, it's better to [ask follow-up questions in a new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-follow-up-questions).